# How to re-write this recurrence in linear form?

Tags: recurrence-relations, substitution

I have the following recurrence

$$T(n) = \frac{1 - T(n - 1)}{T(n - 2)}$$

and $T(0) = a, T(1) = b$. I re-wrote it as such

$$T(n)T(n - 2) = 1 - T(n - 1)$$

I am now trying to re-write this in linear form by making some sort of substitution. What could I do to make this recurrence linear?

Comment: Were you told that it is possible ?

Comment: yes @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t *exactly* an answer to your question, but I think it’s relevant. I doubt there will be a nice way to express $T$ linearly, because it turns out that $T$ is actually *periodic.* This becomes clear after calculating the first couple of terms:
$$\color{green}{T(2)=\frac{1-b}{a}}$$
$$\color{green}{T(3)=\frac{a+b-1}{ab}}$$
$$T(4)=\frac{1-a}{b}$$
$$T(5)=\frac{a+b-1}{ab}$$
$$\color{green}{T(6)=\frac{1-b}{a}}$$
$$\color{green}{T(7)=\frac{a+b-1}{ab}}$$

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot.